# $E[X_n|X_{n-1}] = E[E[X] \cdot X_{n-1}]?$

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

I saw this step while reading up on branching proccesses. $X_i$ is the size of the in the $i$th generation and $\mu$ is the mean number of offspring per individual.

$E[X_n|X_{n-1}]$

$\mu E[X_{n-1}]$

So I'll try and reverse the steps...

$\mu E[X_{n-1}]$

$E[\mu \cdot X_{n-1}]$

$E[E[X] \cdot X_{n-1}]$

But I can't see how I can go from there to

$E[X_n|X_{n-1}]$

Is that some standard identity for expected values that I haven't seen?

Comment: can you please put the definition of $X_n$? this is not true in general.

Comment: Fixed the typo(s).

Comment: there is still no definition.

Comment: @csss http://math.arizona.edu/~faris/stoch.pdf (p.25)